# Is there a Confluence plugin based on SVG-edit?

Tags: confluence, svg-edit

I'm impressed by the ease of use of SVG-edit, having a sketch editor like that in Confluence would be great! I could not find such a plugin, does anyone know more?

Comment: It looks like there is a solution, but it will require some work I think. Here are two resources that might help: https://wiki.cast.org/display/opensource/SVG+Edit+Simple+Interface https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/58890/confluence-xhtml-user-macro-producing-interactive-svg-stuck-in-development

Comment: Alternatively, you could try out Gliffy http://www.gliffy.com/products/confluence-plugin/

Comment: I actually digged down into atlassian plugin and SVG-edit development, from which I learned a lot, hope I get it smooth and stable some day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is now yes, there is, see [this new Confluence plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.bluenode.confluence.sketch)

Comment: the page says the app has been 'archived' - is it no longer an option?

Comment: I was the original author, but don't maintain the plugin anymore, 14 years have passed... There should exist plenty of other solutions in the meantime.

Comment: if you know of any current options (for editing + rendering SVG), please post them!